# Binary reading data from exe file

Tags: c#

I want to read data from exe file. 
On java i read exe perfect from start to end,
bun on c# i cannot read all file. 
File lenth is true but in result show only head of exe file

```
string fileLoc = filePaths[0];
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
  foreach(byte b in bin){
   Console.Write((char)b);
                }
fs.Close();
```

output is only the head of exe: MZP

Comment: Use File.ReadAllBytes instead -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce:

```
        string fileLoc = //my path to git.exe
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        foreach (byte b in bin)
        {
            Console.Write((char)b);
        }
        fs.Close()
```

It writes all data from it.

But i see many problems in your code:

1) never do work with files with such unsafer way (if error occured file will not close) rewrite:

```
       string fileLoc = //my path to git.exe
        using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        foreach (byte b in bin)
        {
            Console.Write((char)b);
        }
       } // no more explicit close required, but it will closed with guarantee
```

2) not mistake but in C# it's preferable use var (analoug to auto in c++)

```
       using(var fs = new FileStream(fileLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
        var br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        var  bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        foreach (var b in bin)
        {
            Console.Write((char)b);
        }
       } //it still strong typed, but type referenced only once at right side of assigment
```

3) Not require use Convert for explicitly castable types (long->int)

```
   var  bin = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
```

4) I don't know why only MZP is written in your case, but can imagine that if you cast byte to char you will get many not-printable symbols including \r \n \f and so on in output - how your concrete terminal will be react? - i don't know

5) If you print (char)b just for test of `bin` - why so badly - why you not simply test bin.Length or why you print `(char)b` and not `b+" "` ? Otherwise if you really want to print bytes to console - it's bad idea anyway - look (4)

6) Why BinaryReader? if you just want read all

```
       using(var fs = new FileStream(fileLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
        var bin = new byte[(int)fs.Length];
        // u can use usual  stream pattern 
        int l=0; while((l+=fs.Read(bin,t,bin.Length-t))<bin.Length);
        foreach (var b in bin)
        {
            Console.Write((char)b);
        }
       }
```

Comment: Another method to control would be to make a md5 over the original file and what is read to see if they are identical

Comment: I don't know what's for author reads whole bin document to byte[] - it seems that his task is not clear too )))

Comment: я впервые пишу на с#, на java как то все отлично написал и содержимое отобразило в консольке, возможно это visual studio не отображает символы? у меня просто выводит заголовок   и дальше пусто. Вообще мне нужно получить просто все содержимое ехе файла

Comment: Кончено, тут вопрос не в C# а в матчасти как таковой. Никогда не следует считать, что бинарный файл можно просто так запросто писать в ASCII - там печатных символов с гулькин нос. Лучше отучиться от этой привычки вставлять print где надо и не надо.

Comment: а как можно корректно отобразить содержимое?

Comment: а что ты (вы) конкретно хочешь? что для тебя корректно? бинарные данные в принципе не имеют однозначного корректного читаемого побайтового отображения.

Comment: Если тебе нужно сравнивать файлы что они идентичны например, то тебе вообще не надо его весь читать в память и что-то там делать. Достаточно взять MD5 с потока (128 бит) и потом их сравнивать.

Comment: Если тебе нужно куда-то файл отправлять и нужен именно текстовой формат (JSON/XML) то тогда используют обычно Base64, в .NET это Convert.ToBase64..., FromBase64.. методы

Comment: Если тебе нужно для хардкодного изучения данных, то используют HEX запись - байт в HEX - в .NET это `mybyte.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, "0");` (преобразовать бвйт в хекс и выровнять 0 по парвому краю) получится что то типа AD4403FF и т.д. и т.п. - по 2 символа на байт.

Comment: На java idea отображает содержимое в таком виде http://i68.tinypic.com/maasz5.png , я хочу добиться что бы я мог содержимое файла вывести в таком виде на с#.

Comment: Gentlemen, could you please stick to English? The whole point of a public forum like SO is that anyone in the world may benefit from the discussion, not just the OP.

Comment: А что хорошего в этом отображении? Ведь все что там показано вопросами - это много очень разных символов за ними на самом деле. И это свойство консоли конкретной IDE, что символ типа \1 \2 и т.д. и т.п она все рисует как "?", а что будет если в файле попадется 100 переносов строк к ряду?  В общем когда уже не одно поколение программистов (включая джавистов) даже не задумываются о такой фиче, а тебе без нее очень плохо - скорее всего нужно задать вопрос, а как же остальные работают с бинарными файлами и не парятся за печать их в консоль? ))))

Comment: я понял) суть была в том, что мне нужно дописать текст в конец exe, а потом считать обратно)